# form which submits via AJAX which returns a JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I have my form set up and the jquery written but I've have no idea what to write for the PHP that should be in mail.php.

Any help would be awesome

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="GET">
   <fieldset>
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="">
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
       <label for="enquiry">Message</label>
       <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" width="100%" height="100px" required=""></textarea>
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Enquiry">
   </fieldset>

</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#contact-form").submit( function (){
    $.getJSON('mail.php',$(this).serialize(), function(data) { 
        if(data['success'] == 1)
        {
            $('#contact-form').html("<p class=\"success\">"+data['message']+"</p>");
        }
        else
        {
                alert(""+data['message']+"");
                $('#contact-form *').removeClass('error');
                for(key in data.errors)
                {
                    $('#'+key).addClass('error');
                }
        }
    });
    return false;
});

});
```

PHP:

```
?
```

Comment: Did you even google for an PHP e-mail example?

Comment: Firstly, have you actually done any research of your own? Secondly, what do you want the form to do? Is it supposed to send out an email to a specified address? Add to a DB? We really need more information, and you'll get on much better by trying to figure this out yourself first, and then asking for assistance if it doesn't work!

Comment: My apologies for being so vague. Usually I'd be more than happy to sit and work this out but after giving it ago and with no prior PHP knowledge I just ended up confusing myself and reached out on here

Comment: OK. Check this page: http://php.net/mail. Usually you can enter: php.net/[your keyword here] and hit enter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in server-side

```
parse_str($_GET["data"],$array);

mail($array["email"]);
```

in jquery

```
 $.getJSON('mail.php',{"data":$(this).serialize()}, function(data) { ...

                  or

var data=$("#contact-form").serialize();
$.ajax(
url:'mail.php';
{data:{"data":data},
datatype:"json",
success:(function(data){

   if(data['success'] == 1)
        {
            $('#contact-form').html("<p class=\"success\">"+data['message']+"</p>");
        }
        else
        {
                alert(""+data['message']+"");
                $('#contact-form *').removeClass('error');
                for(key in data.errors)
                {
                    $('#'+key).addClass('error');
                }
        } 
    })
```

Comment: You forgot to `mail` the array!

Comment: I still don't see a [`mail`](http://php.net/mail)

Comment: @321X which `mail` are you talking about?

Comment: His question is how to e-mail. So I miss the `mail` stuff: http://php.net/mail